# pythonからsinaweibopyパッケージを使ってweiboの投稿を取得したいですがERRORが出る。

Tags: python

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいです。#!/usr/bin/env python

weiboというモジュールを提供するパッケージが二種類あります。
weiboパッケージとsinaweibopyパッケージです。

下記のリンクからsinaweibopyとpythonの情報取得しました
http://github.liaoxuefeng.com/sinaweibopy/
https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO

---

[weiboのaccess_tokenについて](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/)

```
{"access_token":"2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE","remind_in":"157679999","expires_in":157679999,"uid":"5973036902”}
code=682ac33cecf21d6efee0882e2a91eba4
```

[pythonからweiboの投稿を取得について](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO)

[(API_KEYなどの情報が載っています](http://open.weibo.com/apps/294703483/info/basic)

私はsinaweibopyパッケージから投稿を取得したいですがErrorが出る。
上記のリンクで書かれた通りにダウンロード（sinaweibopyパッケージ）などしましたがAPIClientのエラーが出ます。

```
from weibo import APIClient
import urllib2
import urllib
import sys
import time
from time import clock
import csv
import random

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

'''Step 0 Login with OAuth2.0'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP_KEY = '294703483' # app key
    APP_SECRET = 'a2ef9de0a580edb7a26daf2804d27624' # app secret
    CALLBACK_URL = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/default.html' # set callback url exactly like this!
    AUTH_URL = 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/authorize'
    USERID = 'xxxxxxxxx' # your weibo user id
    PASSWD = 'xxxxxxx' #your pw


    client = APIClient(app_key=APP_KEY, app_secret=APP_SECRET, redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL)
    referer_url = client.get_authorize_url()
    print "referer url is : %s" % referer_url

    cookies = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookies)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    postdata = {"client_id": APP_KEY,
                "redirect_uri": CALLBACK_URL,
                "userId": USERID,
                "passwd": PASSWD,
                "isLoginSina": "0",
                "action": "submit",
                "response_type": "code",
                }
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0",
                "Host": "api.weibo.com",
                "Referer": referer_url
            }

    req  = urllib2.Request(
       url = AUTH_URL,
       data = urllib.urlencode(postdata),
       headers = headers
       )
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        print "callback url is : %s" % resp.geturl()
        code = resp.geturl()[-32:]
        print "code is : %s" %  code
    except Exception, e:
        print e

r = client.request_access_token(code)
access_token1 = r.access_token # The token return by sina
expires_in = r.expires_in

print "access_token=" ,access_token1
print "expires_in=" ,expires_in   # access_token lifetime by second. http://open.weibo.com/wiki/OAuth2/access_token

"""save the access token"""
client.set_access_token(access_token1, expires_in)
```

実行結果

```
[root@localhost デスクトップ]# python yoso.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yoso.py", line 3, in <module>
    from weibo import APIClient
ImportError: cannot import name APIClient
```

もしわかる方いれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: weiboモジュールのインストールが正しくできていません。yoso.pyと同じディレクトに保存して再度実行して見てください。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございました。もう一度、インストールしましたが、下記のメッセージが表示されます。Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sinaweibopy==1.1.3 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/d2/a2/875cf8716a8fbb980a251143d0dfd2f23c3febd46015195d2757c6abd813/sinaweibopy-1.1.3.tar.gz in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: う〜ん、となると分かりません。こちらでも試して見ましたが、同じ1.1.3で特に問題なくいけてます。`which python`と`which pip`として結果を見比べて見てくださいbinまでのpathは同じですよね?

Comment: which pythonとwhich pipでやってみると下記のメッセージが表示されます。インストールが正しくないですか。

Comment: [root@localhost デスクトップ]# which pip sinaweibopy
/usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/which: no sinaweibopy in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/root/bin)
[root@localhost デスクトップ]# which python  sinaweibopy
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/which: no sinaweibopy in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/root/bin)

Comment: `sinaweibopy`は不要です。`which python`だけ`which pip`だけ入力して実行してください

Comment: which python の場合[root@localhost デスクトップ]# which python
/usr/bin/python　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　which pipの場合[root@localhost デスクトップ]# which pip
/usr/bin/pip
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 特に問題なしですね。すみません、分かりません。ソースコード中に画面に現れない文字が入っているのかも。`from weibo import APIClient`の行を一度消して、もう一度打ち込んで見ると良いかも。